# Set same random value twice in one query for encryption in MySql

Tags: mysql, variables

I need to update and encrypted table ( the whole table ) without using stored procedure. 
The encryption requires both key, and random array byte. the random array byte will be stored in the same table

```
update employee set name = aes_encrypt(name,'key',@RANDOM_BYTES), random_bytes = @RANDOM_BYTES;
```

the first and second @RANDOM_BYTES should match. so we encrypt the value and store the random value in the same table for decryption later.

I wonder if that is possible at all.

I can use multiple queries, but not stored procedures.

Comment: This is not very clear to me. MYSQL already has a random bytes function as you note in your query. If you want to update the whole table, then you can simply loop through and have a varible in the local scope inside the loop then call that variable.

Comment: The very last two sentences in my (excruciatingly long) answer should be at the very top of my answer, I'll repeat those two sentences here. "I think the much bigger issue security-wise is storing the decryption key on the *same row* with encrypted value. The encrypted value is only secure if the key is secured"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not 100% absolutely, positively sure, but I am fairly certain that MySQL evaluates SETs left to right, so this slight modification should work:

```
UPDATE employee 
SET random_bytes = @RANDOM_BYTES
   , name = aes_encrypt(name,'key',random_bytes)
;
```

Edit: You can actually use this aspect to do stuff like swap integer values between two columns in the same row (though, obviously, the SET for that is much more complicated.)

Comment: works, can you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30494034/replace-temp-column-with-variable-in-an-update-mysql-query

Comment: @Uueerdo: (I just posted an answer, I'd started answering it, got distracted by something more urgent.) I was thinking the question was more involved than just this. Your answer is 100% absolutely correct *for* MySQL. This MySQL "feature" is a deviation from ("enhancement to?") the SQL standard. The SQL standard says that the second reference to `random_bytes` should return the value that was in the row, before it was modified by the statement. (I know 100% for a fact that this does *not* work with Oracle.)

Comment: @spencer7593 Yeah, my experience lies mainly with MySQL, I would not trust this to work elsewhere, but it does make me think of something. The question specified no stored procs, but if TRIGGERs were an option, the issue could be resolved by simply having the trigger take care of the actual decrypt/re-encrypt whenever the key field was changed.

Comment: @spencer7593, I am guessing/hoping he is using that as a "salt" for a larger key.

Answer (score 0):

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** I'm not a cryptographer. I'm not recommending this approach to securing your data by "encrypting" it in this way.

As far as updating a row, you may be able to take advantage of a MySQL deviation from ("extension to?") from the SQL standard.

With a statement like this:

```
UPDATE mytable 
   SET col1 = 'foo'
     , col2 = col1
```

`col1` and `col2` end up with the same value, `'foo'`, because the reference to `col1` in the second assignment returns the value that was just assigned to `col1` (the previous assignment. The order is important here!)

I think the MySQL `AES_ENCRYPT` function takes two arguments, not three, so I'm a little confused by the example you show.

As an example of the approach to the update (setting aside for a moment how you would replace @RANDOM_BYTES with something that gets you a value you can use):

```
UPDATE employee 
   SET random_bytes = @RANDOM_BYTES
     , encrypted_name = AES_ENCRYPT(name,random_bytes)
```

I strongly recommend you test this, and verify it does what you want, on test data in a test environment, before relying on it someplace important.

Be sure that the `encrypted_name` column is defined as "binary" type, e.g. `VARBINARY` (of sufficient length to hold the encrypted/padded value) or `BLOB`. Either that, or, you'd need to encode the binary value, using for example HEX or base64 encoding, so it can be stored in a character column.

As far as returning a value in place of `@RANDOM_BYTES`, that's going to look a little complicated.

We can use repeated calls to `RAND()` to return pseudo-random values, but we need to get that into 128-bit binary value, or, whatever key length is required for `AES_ENCRYPT`.

I'm thinking out loud here...

`FLOOR(RAND()*256.0)` will get us an integer value between 0 and 255, that'd be enough for a random byte.

The `MD5()` function will return us 128-bit value (16-byte), represented in 32 hex digits.

The `SHA2()` function returns values longer than that, we can certainly trim that to whatever length we need.

The trick is going to be getting enough randomness into those hash functions, I'm thinking a single float value isn't going to be enough randomness. We might be able to make use of some other value(s) from the row as a "salt", in combination with some random bytes.

We need to be careful about which functions return hex character strings, and which return BINARY.

We could get two pseudo-random binary bytes like this:

```
CHAR(FLOOR(RAND()*256*256) USING BINARY)
```

If we concatenate eight repetitions of that together, that would get us 16 bytes of binary data. We can get a little less randomness, generating 4 bytes at a time, and concatenating a series of four of these:

```
CHAR(FLOOR(RAND()256*256*256*256) USING BINARY)
```

I'm thinking something like this, though we definitely want to test that expression intended to return a random 16-byte binary value

```
random_binary VARBINARY(16)

UPDATE employee 
   SET random_bytes = -- 16-byte pseudo-random binary string
           CONCAT( CHAR(FLOOR(RAND()256*256*256*256) USING BINARY)
                 , CHAR(FLOOR(RAND()256*256*256*256) USING BINARY)
                 , CHAR(FLOOR(RAND()256*256*256*256) USING BINARY)
                 , CHAR(FLOOR(RAND()256*256*256*256) USING BINARY)
                 )
     , encrypted_name = AES_ENCRYPT(name,random_bytes)
```

---

With this approach, it is critically important that the random_bytes column be defined a "binary" type, e.g. `VARBINARY(16)`.

Also, the value stored in `encrypted_name` will be BINARY, so that needs to be defined as BINARY as well... the AES encryption adds padding (there's a formula somewhere for that, depends on the key length... that column will certainly need to be longer than name.

If we think that storing BINARY might present a problem somewhere along the way, e.g. a characterset translation gets inadvertently applied later, we can encode the binary as hex digits, and store that

```
random_hex VARCHAR(32)

UPDATE employee 
   SET random_hex = -- 16-byte pseudo-random binary as 32 hex digits
         HEX(
           CONCAT( CHAR(FLOOR(RAND()256*256*256*256) USING BINARY)
                 , CHAR(FLOOR(RAND()256*256*256*256) USING BINARY)
                 , CHAR(FLOOR(RAND()256*256*256*256) USING BINARY)
                 , CHAR(FLOOR(RAND()256*256*256*256) USING BINARY)
           )
         )
     , encrypted_name_hex = HEX(AES_ENCRYPT(name,UNHEX(random_bytes)))
```

---

NOTE: I'm not sure if AES_ENCRYPT returns binary or hex, that may depend on the version of MySQL that you're running. I'm also not sure about the key length.

A longer key length would be "more secure" than a shorter one, but it depends on the encryption algorithm. Also, the `RAND()` function isn't "truly" random...

I think the much bigger issue security-wise is storing the decryption key on the same row with encrypted value. The encrypted value is only secure if the key is secured.

Comment: *DOH!* With MySQL 5.6.x, the `RANDOM_BYTES` function was introduced. The painfully complex expressions in this answer would be suitable (?) emulation of RANDOM_BYTES in earlier versions of MySQL, 5.1 and 5.5. (It was probably expressions akin to the ones in this answer  that led to the introduction of the `RANDOM_BYTES` function.

Answer (score -1):

You can use cursors to loop through each row. Please see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html

and all you will need to do is simply define a variable inside the loop scope, that way it will be generated once.

```
SET Bytes = @RANDOM_BYTES
```

From that point on, you can simply update the whole table with the same random bytes for both columns.